# Python Pandas Date in format 'Thursday, March 03, 2019' want to convert to %m/%d/%y

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am using the python pandas and datetime libraries to convert dates in a date column from the following format: 'Thursday, March 03, 2019' to: '3/3/2019'.

Below is the code I am using to get me the result, but I continue to get a ValueError. 'Unconverted Data Remains'.

Does anyone know a way around this issue?

`df_['Date'] = df_['Date'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x, '%A, %B %d, %Y').strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))`

Comment: try: `pd.to_datetime(df_['Date'],errors='coerce').dt.normalize()`

Comment: It seems that you have some values in the 'Date' column which have more information than just that format. The format string expects all values to be converted if there is leftover information it will raise that value error.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `exact=False` in `pandas.to_datetime` if your date string is part of some other string.

***exact*** behaviour : If True, require an exact format match. - If False, allow the format to match anywhere in the target string.

ex :

```py
In [6]: pd.to_datetime("Send this to me on Thursday, March 31, 2015", format='%A, %B %d, %Y', exact=False)                            
Out[6]: Timestamp('2015-03-31 00:00:00')
```